# Avoid that SetFocus raises an Exception

Tags: delphi, vcl, setfocus

I am working at a huge, legacy source code where several `SetFocus` is called at many places, but sometimes, the check if the control is visible or enabled is missing.

Due to limited time, and the huge amount of source code, I decided that I want to ignore these errors, since the focus is (in our case) not a critical feature. A raised Exception will result in a complete failure, while a missing focus is just an optical issue.

My current plan is following:

1. I create an unit with a class helper like this:

   type
   TWinControlEx = class helper for TWinControl
   procedure SetFocusSafe;
   end;

   procedure TWinControlEx.SetFocusSafe;
   begin
   if CanFocus then SetFocus;
   end;
2. I include the unit to every unit which uses ".SetFocus" (I will use the global code search)
3. I replace every .SetFocus with .SetFocusSafe

There is a problem though: If possible, I want to avoid that coworkers accidently use .SetFocus , or forget to include the classhelper unit.

Which other options do I have?

The best case would be if there is a technique/hack to make SetFocus not raising an exception. (Without recompiling the VCL)

Comment: It would  be far easier to fix the code properly than what you are suggesting.

Comment: Agreed that the best solution is just to fix it.  If you're calling `SetFocus` on a control that cannot be focused then your code has somehow gotten out of sync with the expected state of the application.  This points to broader problems where you are executing code in an inappropriate context.  If the state of the application is not what you expect then it suggests that something else has gone wrong previously that may cascade into even more problems going forward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just patch the `TWinControl.SetFocus` method:

```
unit SetFocusFix;

interface

implementation

uses
  Controls,
  Forms,
  SysUtils,
  Windows;

type
  TWinControlHack = class(TWinControl)
  public
    procedure SetFocus; override;
  end;

procedure TWinControlHack.SetFocus;
var
  Parent: TCustomForm;
begin
  if not CanFocus then Exit;

  Parent := GetParentForm(Self);
  if Parent <> nil then
    Parent.FocusControl(Self)
  else if ParentWindow <> 0 then
    Windows.SetFocus(Handle)
  else
    ValidParentForm(Self);
end;

procedure RedirectFunction(OrgProc, NewProc: Pointer);
type
  TJmpBuffer = packed record
    Jmp: Byte;
    Offset: Integer;
  end;
var
  n: UINT_PTR;
  JmpBuffer: TJmpBuffer;
begin
  JmpBuffer.Jmp := $E9;
  JmpBuffer.Offset := PByte(NewProc) - (PByte(OrgProc) + 5);
  if not WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess, OrgProc, @JmpBuffer, SizeOf(JmpBuffer), n) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;

initialization
  RedirectFunction(@TWinControl.SetFocus, @TWinControlHack.SetFocus);

end.
```

Comment: Unfortunately this hack sometimes doesn't work. It means that TWinControlHack.SetFocus is called but application raises exception EInvalidOperation "Cannot focus a disabled or invisible window." on line Parent.FocusControl(Self). I don't know how to make this happen on request. I noticed this while analysing bugreport file from customer. As workaround I placed whole method into try catch block. I meet this error occasionaly few years. I thought that your solution will be final.

Comment: CanFocus is  **BROKEN**  (or incomplete in Delphi). Please check this article on how to [fix it](https://gabrielmoraru.com/setfocus-is-broken-in-delphi/)

Comment: @IceCold This link is already broken.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien - I think it was only temporary. It works now.

Comment: @truthseeker - A control that is parented by a disabled or invisible ctrl cannot be focused. So, the code should also test for that. Also, the code should go multiple levels deep.  It has to check the parent of the parent, of the parent..., up to the top control/form.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively

```
  TWinControlEx = class helper for TWinControl
    procedure SetFocus; reintroduce;
  end;
```

with...

```
procedure TWinControlEx.SetFocus;
var
  Parent: TCustomForm;
begin
  if not CanFocus then Exit;
  Parent := GetParentForm(Self);
  if Parent <> nil then
    Parent.FocusControl(Self)
  else if ParentWindow <> 0 then
    Winapi.Windows.SetFocus(Handle)
  else
    ValidParentForm(Self);
end;
```

Comment: Hi J. A control that is parented by a disabled or invisible ctrl cannot be focused. Your code should also test for that. Also, your code only goes one level deep.  It has to check also the parent of the parent, of the parent....

Answer (score 4):

My answer below does not answer DIRECTLY your question, but it is still relevant because you rely on CanFocus. CanFocus returns a lie. You should not rely on it. The documentation is also wrong. More exactly, CanFocus can return True even if the control is not focusable. In this case, an exception will be raised.
PS: Under Lazarus CanFocus works properly.

So, you will have to write a new CanFocus that tests not only the state of the current control but ALL its parents. You will end up with a recursive call.
Only then you can write a new SetFocus that really works:

```
procedure SetFocus(Control: TWinControl);
begin
 if CanFocusFixed(Control)
 then Control.SetFocus;
end;
```

Full code and explanation here in this article: [Setfocus-is-broken-in-Delphi](https://gabrielmoraru.com/setfocus-is-broken-in-delphi/)

(SO rules state that I have to disclaim that I am affiliate to that website, so: that's my website)

---

Justification:

J provided a nice answer, but PERSONALLY I don't like class helpers because if you have more than one class helper for the same class, then only one will be used - which one is determined (almost randomly) by the order of the units in the "uses" clause. Accidentally change the order of the units in the "uses" and you accidentally change the behavior of your program! I don't like this amount of randomness in a programming language.
Until Emba comes with a stable solution, I won't use Class Helpers.